# Unix equivalent of windows terminal server options?

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop

I want to replace *Windows terminal server* mostly due to cost reasons license cost for 2100 users goes out of roof.

The end-user is all windows but I want a jump server that is UNIX based , I have some experience with VNC but I don't want options exists in UNIX to run a terminal services for 2100 users. Some of the basic requirement for such a setup be:-

- use of browser to access web based application
- Restrict or limit desktop application based upon user authorization.
- Supporting concurrent users for about 1200 per server.

Please let me know how should I go about.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You should read [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, this may be off topic as a too open ended.

Comment: Your question looks like something a boss would ask its IT team to begin a 1-2 year reengineering process that will involve writing hundreds of pages of impact and technical analysis.  You just don't get to save money by saying so, you need a really huge amount of work to do this type of change.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend.  He says that "Linux Terminal Server Project (LTSP) is a free and open source terminal server for Linux that allows many people to simultaneously use the same computer. Applications run on the server with a terminal known as a thin client (also known as an X terminal) handling input and output."  There were a variety of additional hits, such as:

http://www.reallylinux.com/docs/setupltsp.shtml

https://www.nomachine.com/terminal-server

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-and-secure-terminal-server-with-linux/

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/279296-linux-alternative-to-ms-terminal-services

and more.  All have good info.